# How do I create a function in r that assigns one person to 3 other person?

Tags: r, random

I would like to create a function that allows me to easily import any name list with last name and first name (2 columns) and then based on that name list, 3 persons should be randomly assigned to 1 other person. Just wondering how can I do that by creating by own function?

```
name.list <- data.frame(StudentNames = c("Person A", "Person B", "Person C", "Person D", "Person E", "Person B"))
NROW.test <- nrow(name.list)

for(i in 1:NROW.test){
  student_1 <- name.list$StudentNames [i + 1] 
  student_2 <- name.list$StudentNames [i+ 2] 
  student_3 <- name.list$StudentNames [i + 3] 
}

test_student_assigned <- data.frame(AssignedStudent = (name.list$StudentNames),
                                   Student_1 = student_1, 
                                   Student_2 = student_2,
                                   Student_3 = student_3, 
                                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using `tidyr` and `dplyr` packages.

We first create a dataframe that will generate 3 random person per unique person.

`df <- data.frame(sapply(name.list$StudentNames, function(x) sample(name.list$StudentNames[x != name.list$StudentNames], 3)), check.names = F)`

We will iterate through the `name.list$StudentNames` and call the `sample` function but have the condition where we exclude the unique person.

We then use `tidyr::pivot_longer` to make the data longer so that the 3 person will be linked to the unique person.

We then group the person and create a numbering system to specify the person number and pivot wide again.

```
test_student_assigned <- df %>% 
    tidyr::pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "AssignedStudent") %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(AssignedStudent) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(n = paste0("Student_",row_number())) %>% 
    tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = n, values_from = value)
```